# Django DRF Serializer Not Saving Nested Model: What Am I Missing?

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**django drf nested serializer saving issue**

i'm not able to save my model due to some nested serializer id issue,
i will share my model

```
class Duration(models.Model):
    start_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    end_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        self.end_time


class VideoMaker(models.Model):
    CHOICE_SELECT = [
        ('vo','voice over'),
        ('bg_music','backgournd music'),
        ('video_music','vidio music'),
    ]
    typee = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=CHOICE_SELECT)
    high_volume = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    low_volume = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    video_component_id = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True,blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    duration = models.ForeignKey(Duration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

My Serializer:

```
class DuratinSeriaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Duration
        fields = [
            'id',
            'start_time',
            'end_time',
        ]


class VideoMakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    duration = DuratinSeriaizer()
    class Meta:
        model = VideoMaker
        fields = [
            'id',
            'typee',
            'high_volume',
            'low_volume',
            'video_component_id',
            'url',
            'duration',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        datas = validated_data.pop('duration')
        duration_data = VideoMaker.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for datas in datas:
            Duration.objects.create(duration=duration_data,**datas)
        Duration.save()
        return duration_data
```

my views:

```
class AudioCreateApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = VideoMaker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoMakerSerializer
```

if i'm wrong please help me out!

The error i'm getting
''' NOT NULL constraint failed: VideoMaker_videomaker.duration_id '''
im not able to save, i'm helpless

i'm Expecting :

```
    {
        "id": 6,
        "typee": "vo",
        "high_volume": 65,
        "low_volume": 123,
        "video_component_id": "wertyuio",
        "url": "",
        "duration": {
            "id": 9,
            "start_time": 21,
            "end_time": 98
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    datas = validated_data.pop('duration')
    instance = Duration.objects.create(**datas)
    duration_data = VideoMaker.objects.create(duration=instance,**validated_data)
    return duration_data
```

in VideoMaker model u give foreign so instance must be assigned to VideoMaker table.
Use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` to debug your code.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.